# Round shaped button getting distorted with length of text inside.

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button

I'm trying to have a perfectly round shaped button.

I have tried with the below code using shape.
but issue i am facing is that when the view has two text in it, it looks almost a circle but as soon as the view has one and three character in it it looks oval shaped.

**shape code**

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="true">


       <corners android:bottomRightRadius="20dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dip"  
        android:topRightRadius="20dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dip"
        />


       </shape>
```

[image]

Please check the nearly rounded shaped button where number 2 and 22 are written in the picture
I have used the same code for all of the buttons(mentioned above)

[image]

Comment: Can you show the xml layout where you are using this shape ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your layout file (or in code), keep the dimensions of the Button fixed (width=height=some dp).
In example:

```
layout_width="48dp"
layout_height="48dp"
```